How to exempt a folder from Readonly Windows network share?
I am sharing a folder as readonly via Windows networking so that users in the network can execute programs. However there are folders in the share that the programs need to write to. Is there a way to exempt those folders?

If the network share is set to read-only then write actions are impossible. The only way for you is to set the NTFS permissions for all users that use the share to read-only and only allow write in the folders you need. then enable write mode on the share.
